# How to display a bar chart for users' test scores if you have more than 50 users

Tags: usability, info-visualisation, data, dashboard, charts

For an admin panel I have to present visually the employees' test scores and after lots of searching to decide which data visualization is the best I decided to choose the vertical bar chart but as the number of employees can increase up to more than 50 I can not use the vertical bar chart so I change it to horizontal one but the problem is it gets too long and the admin has to scroll down to see all the employees' score and can't make a good comparison of all the scores.
So can anyone help me with how can I show all scores in one visual element without too much scrolling? [image: horizontal bar chart]

Comment: In his answer Mike suggests "Think about what the real task of the admin is here". Once you can define the tasks admins need to accomplish you'll be able to design the data controls needed. I question the assertion admins need to "make a good comparison of all the scores.". ...too broad, general, and vague to qualify as a design requirement.

Comment: Consider a histogram for large-scale comparison.

Answer (score 2):

##### Think about what the real task of the admin is here

> the admin has to scroll down to see all the employees' score and can't make a good comparison of all the scores.

Space will almost always be an issue in most UI (what happens when it's 100 employees?). What you could do, is use a kind of search and filter, where you could pull up a number of employees at once.

It seems like the core task is comparison and finding employees to see where they sit on the chart.

If I have 50 employees, I can't compare all 50 at once (especially if I'm looking around for several at a time, and I have to keep scanning up and down the list), but I might have several I wish to compare (or a team), but each sits at different positions in the ranking order.

Here's a rough sketch of an idea:

[image]

A lot of data visualization and dashboards uses a pattern of getting the big picture first (the larger graph), then drilling into details (filtering).

Comment: Thanks. Your solution sounds great.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles
 Yes, you are right thanks. What I have found from the user research was that admins need to compare employees' performance based on age and gender. I think I should consider the gender and age filter.

Comment: @Luke Sawczak Thanks alot
I didn't have experience designing a histogram before, but I will try to see how it works here in my project.